# React JSX error expected a return value at the end of the arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running this code:

```
books.map(({ subjects, formats, title, authors, bookshelves }, index) => {
                subjects = subjects.join().toLowerCase();
                author = authors.map(({ name }) => name).join();
                if (!text && subjects.includes(category) === true) {.....some code....
                }
});
```

Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function `array-callback-return` at line 1 in the above code.
I tried to return but it is not working.
Is it ok if I ignore these warnings?
I am using this for production, do I need really need to solve this, or is it ok to leave it.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, it could be best to use either a `forEach` or `reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

`map` does expect a return value and is considered an anti-pattern when not using it to build an array. It's probably ok, but better to use `forEach` instead.

Example using forEach:

```js
[{subjects: ['history', 'math'], authors: [{name: 'author 1'},{name: 'author 2'}]}].forEach((item) => {
                let subjects = item.subjects.join().toLowerCase();
                let authors = item.authors.map(({ name }) => name).join();
           console.log(subjects, authors);     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It expects a return value because you are using `.map`, use `.foreach` instead. You can learn more here: [Map vs. ForEach](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to return a value, you can use `forEach` to get rid of the warning.

`return null;` will also do the job but, it is not recommended.