# React: Error Returning Value in Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**BLUF: I checked this similar Stack Overflow: [React JSX error expected a return value at the end of the arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863001/react-jsx-error-expected-a-return-value-at-the-end-of-the-arrow-function), followed the advice, and still have the same problem**

I get the warning `Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function` and my local host server is loading endlessly as a result.

Here is my code:

```
import JSONDATA from './MOCK_DATA.json';
import "./Navbar.css";
import {useState} from 'react'

const Searchbar = () => {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')
    return (
        <div className="Search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." onChange={event => {setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}}/>
            {JSONDATA.filter((val) => {
                if (searchTerm === "") {
                    return ''
                } else if (val.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                    return val
                }

            }).forEach((val, key) => {
                return (
                    <div className="user" key={key}>
                        <p>{val.first_name}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Searchbar
```

Comment: What are you getting? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @David my apologies, I just edited the main response.

Comment: @devintark see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function

The error means exactly what it says.  It's possible that the function you passed to `filter` doesn't return a response (if neither of your `if` conditions are `true`), which is invalid.

Additionally, the function passed to `filter` should be returning a `true` or `false` response.  *Technically* you're trying to do that because `''` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and an object is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).  But that's *probably* not what you meant to do.

If this is the condition you're checking in your `filter`:

> if (val.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))

Then just check that condition:

```
JSONDATA.filter(val => val.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
```

Assuming none of these properties are `null` or `undefined`, `includes()` will return a `true` or `false` value.  If they *might* be `null` or `undefined`, you'll want to add checks for that as well.

---

Additionally, you appear to be misusing `forEach` here.  `forEach` is for looping over an array to perform an operation on each element.  `map` is for projecting an array into a new array, transforming each element.  You appear to be wanting the latter, so replace the `forEach` with `map`.

Comment: Okay, so I followed your advice changed that portion to ```{JSONDATA.filter(val => val.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())).forEach((val, key) => {
                return (
                    <div className="user" key={key}>
                        <p>{val.first_name}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            })}``` But my page is still not loading on the local host.

Comment: @AndrewBregman: `forEach` is probably the wrong tool.  That's for looping over an array to perform an operation.  It looks like you want to project the array into a new array.  Use `map` instead.

Comment: To no avail. Here is the github: https://github.com/andrew-bregman/navbar

Comment: @AndrewBregman: What is the updated code and in what specific way does it fail?  It's entirely possible you've encountered a new, separate problem.

Comment: ```{JSONDATA.filter(val => val.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())).map((val, key) => {
                return (
                    <div className="user" key={key}>
                        <p>{val.first_name}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            })}``` and after running npm start its compiles successfully, but the webpage is endlessly loading. Also, the github is updated with that change.

Comment: @AndrewBregman: That does indeed sound like a separate problem.  You’ll want to do some further debugging and if you can’t trace the problem then you can create a sandboxed example to demonstrate and create a new question for it.